# Computing differential of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(p)=|p-p_0|^2$ where $p\in S$ and $p_0$ is a fixed point of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am trying to show that $df(w)=2w\cdot(p-p_0)$ where $w\in T_p(S)$.

So suppose $\alpha$ is a curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=w$. Let $\beta=f\circ\alpha$. Then I am trying to compute $\beta'(0)$. We have that $\beta(t)=f(\alpha(t))=|\alpha(t)-p_0|^2$.

Then $\beta'(t)=2|\alpha(t)-p_0|\alpha'(t)$, and $\beta'(0)=2|p-p_0|w$.

Is this correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where you went wrong is  $\beta'(t)=2|\alpha(t)-p_0| |\alpha(t)-p_0|'$ and in fact $\beta'(t)\neq2|\alpha(t)-p_0|\alpha'(t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$\beta(t)=f(\alpha(t))=|\alpha(t)-p_0|^2$$ from where

$$\beta'(t)=\langle \alpha(t)-p_0,\alpha(t)-p_0\rangle' =2\langle \alpha'(t),\alpha(t)-p_0\rangle.$$

Note that $\beta:I\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$ So, its derivative must be $\beta':I\subset \mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$ But $2|\alpha(t)-p_0|\alpha'(t)\in \mathbb R^3.$